# Minor confusion over Thompson sampling

Tags: machine-learning, multiarmed-bandit

On a paper concerning Thompson sampling (TS) I found a quote:

> In order to exploit the estimated uncertainties, TS dedicates a higher
>   chance to explore an action if its uncertainty increases.

However I thought TS **chooses actions with a probability proportional to the estimated expected return/reward**.

Are these two points reconcilable or am I or the reference incorrect?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It would be nice if you could link the paper for context.

These two points are reconcilable. In Thompson sampling, you have a reward distribution for each arm. A sample is taken from each arm's distribution, and the arm with the largest sample is chosen. There are two things to note here:

1. The higher expected value an arm's distribution has, the larger its sample is expected to be, and thus has a higher chance of being the arm with the largest sample.
2. The higher variance an arm's distribution has, the larger its sample *could* be (despite possibly having a lower expected value), and thus has a higher chance of being the arm with the largest sample.

Typically, the distributions' variances will decrease as you gather more data. This is the mechanism that controls the exploration-exploitation trade-off in Thompson sampling.

It really is best to visualize these things in a simple setting. [This tool](https://learnforeverlearn.com/bandits/) might be valuable to you in explaining why this is the case.